# Symfony throws "no Response returned" Error even though I return Response

Tags: php, symfony

1) There is this Controller Function I made:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/add", name="add" )
 */
public function add_question()
{
   return $this->render("add.html.twig",[]);
}
```

2) When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/add Symfony returns this error:

```
The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a 
    return statement somewhere in your controller?
```

3) I have bunch of other Controllers that have the same structure and work correctly.

4) Whenever I want to add a new Controller, this error is being thrown.

5) I tried to return Response object - it doesn't work either.

EDIT:
my **config/routes/annotations.yaml** file:

```
controllers:
resource: ../../src/Controller/
type: annotation
```

Comment: Have you checked if the path "/add" is not duplicated for another router? you can see the list of routers by this command  : php bin/console debug:router. You can also var_dump the response just before returning it  to see if  it is not null

Comment: On Symfony 3.*, share `app/config/routing.yml` and on Symfony 4.*, share `config/routes/annotations.yaml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.

I have a few Controllers in my project.
One of them was located almost on top of the file and had following routing:

```
/**
* @Route("/{question_id}", name="questions" )  <--QUESTION ROUTE
*/
```

the logic of controller was like that:

```
function GenerateQuestionPage($question_id)

1find question in my database whose $id is equal to question_id.
2a. If you find such question then render proper twig template.
2b. If You don't find such question then you echo "No such question found";
```

Whenever I wanted to go to some page whose Routing was defined **below** the definition of the GenerateQuestionPage Controller, Symfony thought I was trying to use Question Route with
nonnumerical question_id. Then it was searching for such question in DB but obviously couldn't find so it wasn't returning Response object.

My **solution** was to relocate GenerateQuestionPage controller to the bottom of the file.

Comment: If your IDs do only contain digits, you can add a requirement to let it match only some paths like this: `@Route("/{question_id}", name="questions", requirements={"question_id": "\d+"})` (see also https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements)

Comment: Wow, that's a great solution. Thanks!